# Sending value of One date picker to two textboxes deferent format

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one datepicker how can I send the value in two textboxes with deferent format?
I have used this :

```
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    buttonText: "Select Date",
                    dateFormat: "D dd/mm/yy",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    //maxDate: new Date()
                    onSelect: function () {
                        var copydate = $(".datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
                       $("#FDate").val(copydate);
                        
                    }
                 });
                
            });
        </script>
```

textbox1 which has the class **datepicker** working fine get me the date like this TUE 20/10/2020
but textbox2 called **FDate** get me very long date with extra details I want it to show only 20/10/2020
any help please?
I tried to use `dateformat` after val or after `getdate` but not working.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code? What kind of _very long date_ do you get? Elaborate please.

Comment: It shows Tue Oct 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT +0300 (Official Arabic Date)

Comment: Convert it yourself to your wanted format with [Date methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp). Does that help?

Comment: no Jelmer it does not help only getDate working but get me long date infromation.

Comment: the idea i want when i select a date textbox 1 will have day with date and textbox 2 just only date. t1= D dd/mm/yy , t2= dd/mm/yy. if there is another javascript i will do it.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code too? Then I'll understand it more.

Comment: it just that script I add it in my Create page in MVC 5 no more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var copydate = $(".datepicker").datepicker('getDate');` returns the long date format.

You need to `.formatDate()` the date from the `.datepicker`

```js
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        dateFormat: "D dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(),
        //maxDate: new Date()
        onSelect: function () {
            var datetypevar = $(".datepicker").datepicker('getDate'); 
            var copydate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', datetypevar);
           $("#FDate").val(copydate);     
        }
     });
    
});
```